# Order list of some elements by list of rules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got a list of elements, like `[C, D, B, A]` (every letter is a tuple of RGB color) and a list of rules (first element > second elements):
`[(D,C), (D,B), (D,A), (C,B), (C,A), (B,A)]`, so `D` has to be sorted after `C`, `B` and `A` (so comes last), `C` comes after `B` and `A`, (placing it 3rd), etc.

Correct order is `[A, B, C, D]`:

```
for _ in colors:
    color += [_]
for element in rules:
    listtwo += [(element)]
        
for x in listtwo:
    if x[0] in color:
        color.remove(x[0])
    if x[1] in color:
        color.remove(x[1])

for elements in rules:
    if elements[0] == elements[1]:
        pass
    else:
        listone += [elements]
        for el in listone:
            pos_a = colors.index(el[0])
            pos_b = colors.index(el[1])
            if pos_a > pos_b:
                colors.remove(el[0])
                colors.insert(posizione_b, el[0])

if len(color) > 0:
    colors.remove(colors[0])
colors.reverse()
if len(color) > 0:
    colors.append(colors[0])
```

It works in some specific cases but not in general (And the code is not well written). Any ideas?

Further examples, it works with:

```
colors = [(255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 255), (255, 255, 0)]

rules = [
    ((0, 0, 255), (255, 0, 0)),
    ((0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0)),
    ((0, 255, 0), (255, 0, 0)),
    ((255, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255)),
    ((255, 255, 0), (255, 0, 0)),
    ((255, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0)),
    ((0, 255, 255), (0, 0, 255)),
    ((0, 255, 255), (255, 0, 0)),
    ((0, 255, 255), (0, 255, 0)),
    ((255, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255))
]
```

Output is:

```
[(255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 255), (255, 255, 0)]
```

It doesn't works with this example:

```
colors = [
    (142, 150, 92), (133, 228, 115), (149, 198, 219), (250, 150, 227),
    (79, 247, 87), (197, 223, 252), (104, 132, 238), (121, 154, 210),
    (127, 219, 167), (222, 190, 134), (191, 52, 233)
]

rules = [
    ((79, 247, 87), (250, 150, 227)),
    ((250, 150, 227), (149, 198, 219)),
    ((79, 247, 87), (149, 198, 219)),
    ((79, 247, 87), (133, 228, 115)),
    ((149, 198, 219), (133, 228, 115)),
    ((133, 228, 115), (142, 150, 92)),
    ((250, 150, 227), (142, 150, 92)),
    ((79, 247, 87), (142, 150, 92)),
    ((197, 223, 252), (142, 150, 92)),
    ((197, 223, 252), (250, 150, 227)),
    ((121, 154, 210), (79, 247, 87)),
    ((121, 154, 210), (197, 223, 252)),
    ((121, 154, 210), (142, 150, 92)),
    ((127, 219, 167), (121, 154, 210)),
    ((197, 223, 252), (79, 247, 87)),
    ((127, 219, 167), (79, 247, 87)),
    ((127, 219, 167), (142, 150, 92)),
    ((121, 154, 210), (104, 132, 238)),
    ((104, 132, 238), (197, 223, 252)),
    ((127, 219, 167), (197, 223, 252)),
    ((222, 190, 134), (121, 154, 210)),
    ((191, 52, 233), (121, 154, 210)),
    ((222, 190, 134), (191, 52, 233)),
    ((191, 52, 233), (127, 219, 167)),
    ((191, 52, 233), (222, 190, 134))
```

]

Wrong output:

```
[(142, 150, 92), (133, 228, 115), (149, 198, 219), (250, 150, 227),
 (79, 247, 87), (197, 223, 252), (104, 132, 238), (121, 154, 210),
 (127, 219, 167), (222, 190, 134), (191, 52, 233)]
```

Correct Output:

```
[(142, 150, 92), (133, 228, 115), (149, 198, 219), (250, 150, 227),
 (79, 247, 87), (197, 223, 252), (104, 132, 238), (121, 154, 210),
 (127, 219, 167), (191, 52, 233), (222, 190, 134)]
```

Comment: Please tell us where your code works and where it doesn´t so we can help you better.

Comment: Can you give an example of `colors`and when your code doesn't work.

Comment: Did you mean to _revert_ the sort order here? `D` is **smaller** than `C` if it comes first in the correct sorted output.

Comment: Your letters-only example and your concrete examples are directly contradicting one another. Your correct output for the larger colors list has `(142, 150, 92)` appear first, while it is listed in the rules as coming **after** other colors, where your small letters-only example has `D` come first, which fits if we interpret any `(a, b)` pair in the rules as meaning *a comes before b*.

Comment: When I [put your rules in a graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWrIV.png), you can see there is a circular dependency in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have a *total* order or you could treat this a [*topological sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of a directed graph.

To treat this as a total order (requiring that there are rules for all nodes that produce a consistent order without ambiguities), you need to map your relative ordering rules to a *total ordering* of your inputs. You could use a *comparison* function for this, and then apply the [`functools.cmp_to_key()` utility function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) to make this a proper sort key:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

comes_after = {('C', 'A'), ('B', 'A'), ('D', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('D', 'C'), ('D', 'B')}

@cmp_to_key
def ordering_rules(a, b):
    if a == b: return 0
    return 1 if (a, b) in comes_after else -1

sorted_colors = sorted(colors, key=ordering_rules)
```

I put your rules into a *set*, because membership testing against a set is much more efficient; `(a, b)` is then a tuple that, if present in the `comes_before` set indicates that `a` should be sorted before `b`, so `a < b` is true and `a == b` or `a > b` is false.

Demo:

```
>>> colors = ['C', 'D', 'B', 'A']
>>> sorted(colors, key=ordering_rules)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

The `ordering_rules(a, b)` function acts like an old-fashioned [`cmp()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#the-old-way-using-the-cmp-parameter), which would return a negative number if `a < b` is true, 0 for when `a == b`, and a positive number when `a > b` is true.

The `cmp_to_key()` decorator above just maps that implementations for the `<`, `<=`, `==`, `>` and `>=` operator hooks (`__lt__`, etc.), so that normal sorting can compare any two elements without having to reference the above rules.

In fact, because the current implementation [explicitly uses *just* `<` comparisons to sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort), you can make your own key object to achieve the same, just by giving it a [`__lt__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__).

For future-proofing, however, I'd also implement `__eq__` for equality testing and then add the [`@functools.total_ordering` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) to provide the hooks for the `>`, `>=`, etc.:

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class ColorSortKey:
    comes_after = {('C', 'A'), ('B', 'A'), ('D', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('D', 'C'), ('D', 'B')}
    __slots__ = ('color',)
    
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, ColorSortKey):
            return NotImplemented
        return (other.color, self.color) in self.comes_after

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, ColorSortKey):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.color == other.color
```

I gave the class a [`__slots__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) to help minimise memory use; you can sort very large lists with this class and still keep memory growth in check this way.

You can then use the above in much the same way, as a `key` argument to `list.sort()` or `sorted()`:

```
>>> sorted(colors, key=ColorSortKey)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

If your rules are variable, you could make the rules a parameter that you attach to the class via [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial), perhaps via classmethod for more self-documenting code:

```
from functools import partial, total_ordering

@total_ordering
class ColorSortKey:
    __slots__ = ('color', 'comes_after')

    @classmethod
    def with_rules(cls, rules):
        return partial(cls, set(rules))

    def __init__(self, comes_after, color):
        self.comes_after = comes_after
        self.color = color

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, ColorSortKey):
            return NotImplemented
        return (other.color, self.color) in self.comes_after

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, ColorSortKey):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.color == other.color
```

This lets you use `ColorSortKey.with_rules(rules)` as the sort key. Given your more expanded rules example:

```
>>> sorted(colors, key=ColorSortKey.with_rules(rules))
[(142, 150, 92), (133, 228, 115), (149, 198, 219), (250, 150, 227), (79, 247, 87), (197, 223, 252), (104, 132, 238), (121, 154, 210), (127, 219, 167), (191, 52, 233), (222, 190, 134)]
```

To sort the colors *topologically*, you treat your rules as edges in a directed graph.

To treat this as a topological sort, you could implement one of the [algorithms that Wikipedia lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Algorithms); I'm using Kahn's here:

```py
from heapq import heapify, heappop, heappush

def topological_sort(colors, rules):
    forward = {c: set() for c in colors}
    reverse = {}
    for a, b in rules:
        if forward.keys() >= {a, b}:  # a and be are both in the input list
            forward[b].add(a)
            reverse.setdefault(a, set()).add(b)

    # determine what nodes have no incoming edges
    # this is a set operation: any key in forward that's not a key in reverse
    start = forward.keys() - reverse
    # set up our queue, ensuring we process the next best node (lexicographical order)
    queue = list(start)
    heapify(queue)
    result = []
    while queue:
        node = heappop(queue)
        result.append(node)
        for dep in forward.pop(node, ()):
            reverse[dep].remove(node)
            # only when there are more outgoing edges left
            if not reverse[dep]:
                heappush(queue, dep)

    result += sorted(forward)  # any remaining nodes with circular dependencies

    return result
```

Note that we need to special-case the possibility of **circular dependencies**. Given your first full example, interpreting a rule `(a, b)` as *a comes before b*, gives us:

```py
>>> colors = [(255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 255), (255, 255, 0)]
>>> rules = [((0, 0, 255), (255, 0, 0)), ((0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0)), ((0, 255, 0), (255, 0, 0)), ((255, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255)), ((255, 255, 0), (255, 0, 0)), ((255, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0)), ((0, 255, 255), (0, 0, 255)), ((0, 255, 255), (255, 0, 0)), ((0, 255, 255), (0, 255, 0)), ((255, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255))]
>>> topological_sort(colors, rules)
[(255, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255), (0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0), (255, 0, 0)]
```

or reversing the dependencies:

```py
>>> reversed_rules = [(b, a) for a, b in rules]
>>> topological_sort(colors, reversed_rules)
[(255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 255), (255, 255, 0)]
```

However, your final example is **not** free of circular dependencies. These are your rules, rendered as a directed graph:

[image: directed graph representation of the rules]

If you look closely at these two rules:

```
(222, 190, 134)  >  (191,  52, 233)
(191,  52, 233)  >  (222, 190, 134)
```

you'll see that they lead back to one another. This is why your sort implementation failed here, **either** order is 'correct', in that there is no pure topological sort order possible here, and we need to add these remaining nodes at the end in arbitrary order (I picked lexicographical):

```
>>> topological_sort(colors, rules)
[(142, 150, 92), (133, 228, 115), (149, 198, 219), (250, 150, 227), (79, 247, 87), (197, 223, 252), (104, 132, 238), (121, 154, 210), (127, 219, 167), (191, 52, 233), (222, 190, 134)]
```

**Neither** of these colors could ever win, after all. In the above sorted result, that has led to an arbitrary ordering of `(191, 52, 233), (222, 190, 134)` at the very end, and in your case the two values were reversed. That's not the sorting algorithms' fault, you gave it inconsistent rules, so there is no possibility of a proper total ordering.

Note that as of Python 3.9, you don't have to implement topological sorting yourself, as that version added [`graphlib.TopologicalSorter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/graphlib.html#graphlib.TopologicalSorter). This class makes it trivial to detect a circular dependency in your graph:

```
>>> from graphlib import TopologicalSorter
>>> sorter = TopologicalSorter(dict.fromkeys(colors, ()))
>>> used = set(colors)
>>> for a, b in rules:
...     if used >= {a, b}:
...         sorter.add(a, b)
...
>>> sorted_colors = list(sorter.static_order())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../lib/python3.9/graphlib.py", line 241, in static_order
    self.prepare()
  File "/.../lib/python3.9/graphlib.py", line 103, in prepare
    raise CycleError(f"nodes are in a cycle", cycle)
graphlib.CycleError: ('nodes are in a cycle', [(191, 52, 233), (222, 190, 134), (191, 52, 233)])
```

If you *must* try to get an order, even if arbitrary, you could use that class still but need to catch call [`TopologicalSorter.prepare()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/graphlib.html#graphlib.TopologicalSorter.prepare) directly, then pick off nodes that are ready [have no predecessors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/graphlib.html#graphlib.TopologicalSorter.get_ready), mark them as done as you process them:

```
from graphlib import TopologicalSorter, CycleError

def best_effort_topological_sort(colors, rules):
    sorter = TopologicalSorter(dict.fromkeys(colors, ()))
    used = set(colors)
    for a, b in rules:
        if used >= {a, b}:
            sorter.add(a, b)

    try:
        sorter.prepare()
    except CycleError:
        pass

    result = []
    while sorter.is_active():
        for node in sorter.get_ready():
            used.remove(node)
            result.append(node)
            sorter.done(node)

    if used:
        # circular nodes, append in arbitrary order
        result += sorted(used)

    return result
```

which results in:

```
>>> best_effort_topological_sort(colors, rules)
[(142, 150, 92), (133, 228, 115), (149, 198, 219), (250, 150, 227), (79, 247, 87), (197, 223, 252), (104, 132, 238), (121, 154, 210), (127, 219, 167), (191, 52, 233), (222, 190, 134)]
```

You could play with how the remaining elements are added to the end of the result; you could sort them in lexicographical order, for example (`result += sorted(used)`).

Note that the `TopologicalSorter()` doesn't define an ordering for nodes at the same 'level', where they all have the same number of incoming nodes remaining. My `topological_sort()` function uses a [heap queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) to process nodes in lexicographical order as you clear them from the graph, which can produce a different order from `TopologicalSorter()`, which processes nodes in groups.

In practice, that means that my implementation will produce a stable order regardless of how `colors` or `rules` were initially ordered, whereas using `TopologicalSorter()` can produce different results depending on how these were ordered at the start.

Take this example:

```
colors = [(73, 2, 121), (103, 226, 123), (24, 180, 171), (167, 17, 180), (76, 104, 15), (148, 77, 117)]
rules = [
    ((167, 17, 180), (76, 104, 15)),
    ((148, 77, 117), (103, 226, 123)),
    ((148, 77, 117), (73, 2, 121)),
    ((24, 180, 171), (76, 104, 15)),
    ((148, 77, 117), (167, 17, 180)),
    ((103, 226, 123), (24, 180, 171)),
    ((73, 2, 121), (24, 180, 171))
]
```

Represented as a graph:

[image: specific example as directed graph]

There are two different paths through those rules:

```
>>> topological_sort(colors, rules)
[(76, 104, 15), (24, 180, 171), (73, 2, 121), (103, 226, 123), (167, 17, 180), (148, 77, 117)]
>>> best_effort_topological_sort(colors, rules)
[(76, 104, 15), (167, 17, 180), (24, 180, 171), (103, 226, 123), (73, 2, 121), (148, 77, 117)]
```

That's because, after clearing `(76, 104, 15)`, there are 2 different colors that have no remaining dependencies in the rules,  `(167, 17, 180)` and `(24, 180, 171)`. The `TopologicalSorter()` class will return these in the relative order that we added them to the sorter, while my implementation picks the one lexicographically coming first, so `(24, 180, 171)`.

Next, `TopologicalSorter()` will process both those colors before looking for other colors that remain and now have 0 incoming rules, while my implementation has only removed `(24, 180, 171)` from the queue before adding `(73, 2, 121)` and `(103, 226, 123)` to the queue, and so continues with `(73, 2, 121)` next.

Both orderings are correct according to the rules, but if you were to *shuffle* the rules then `best_effort_topological_sort()` can produce a different ordering again whereas my heapq-based implementation will always produce the same outcome.

Comment: @superbrain: brain fog. I cleared up that  section.

Comment: Try `rules = [(1, 2), (2, 3)]` and `colors = [2, 3, 1]`. You incorrectly produce `[2, 3, 1]`, and this time it's the fault of the algorithm.

Comment: @superbrain: I'd say it's the fault of the question with no clarity on what kind of sort they really need ;-)

Comment: @superbrain: and I actually get `[3, 2, 1]` for both the `ColorSortKey` and `topological_sort()` options (after correcting both question and answer about how the rules are supposed to work).

Comment: I wouldn't say "actually", that sounds like I wasn't telling the truth. With your updated version I indeed get `[3, 2, 1]` now, but now it gets `colors = [1, 3, 2]` wrong. Your `topological_sort` gets all six permutations correct, though.

Comment: @superbrain: Right, and that's because there is no total order defined in the rules; there is no `(1, 3)`. I *think* the OP is looking for a topological sort, but I'll leave both options in place.

Comment: Right, it's not explicitly a total order, although it does fulfill *"requiring that there are rules for all nodes that produce a consistent order without ambiguities"*. Btw, `topological_sort([1, 2], [])` returns `[]` instead of `[1, 2]` or `[2, 1]`.

Comment: @superbrain: that really depends on how the rules are to be interpreted. Should colors that have no rules be included or not?

Comment: Well, at least the title says *"Order list of some elements by list of rules"*, not *"Order **and filter** list of some elements by list of rules"*.

Comment: And darn, you're working hard on making my answer obsolete now...

Comment: You are right, the problem was exactly this:
(222, 190, 134)  >  (191,  52, 233)
(191,  52, 233)  >  (222, 190, 134)

Comment: @superbrain if this is supposed to be a topological sort then you do have to state how to handle unreachable nodes. If they are to be used we could just start the graph with `{c: set() for c in colors}` and put those first (they have no incoming edges).

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "unreachable nodes". Unreachable *from where*? It's not like we have some root. But with what I guess you meant, you still don't *have to* state how to handle it. You *can* if you want to, but you can also be happy enough with *any* valid order.

Comment: @superbrain: I now output those nodes first. I've also added an example that showcases why using a `heapq` to handle 'ready' nodes makes a difference in the outcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`graphlib.TopologicalSorter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/graphlib.html) introduced in Python 3.9:

```
ts = TopologicalSorter()
for color in colors:
    ts.add(color)
for rule in rules:
    ts.add(*rule)
ordered = list(ts.static_order())
```

However, with your rules, this leads to an error

```
graphlib.CycleError: ('nodes are in a cycle', [(191, 52, 233), (222, 190, 134), (191, 52, 233)])
```

That's what Martijn pointed out as well.

But if you remove the incorrect rule, then it gives you the expected result.

Demo:

```
from graphlib import TopologicalSorter

colors = [(142, 150, 92), (133, 228, 115), (149, 198, 219), (250, 150, 227), (79, 247, 87), (197, 223, 252), (104, 132, 238), (121, 154, 210), (127, 219, 167), (222, 190, 134), (191, 52, 233)]
rules = [((79, 247, 87), (250, 150, 227)), ((250, 150, 227), (149, 198, 219)), ((79, 247, 87), (149, 198, 219)), ((79, 247, 87), (133, 228, 115)), ((149, 198, 219), (133, 228, 115)), ((133, 228, 115), (142, 150, 92)), ((250, 150, 227), (142, 150, 92)), ((79, 247, 87), (142, 150, 92)), ((197, 223, 252), (142, 150, 92)), ((197, 223, 252), (250, 150, 227)), ((121, 154, 210), (79, 247, 87)), ((121, 154, 210), (197, 223, 252)), ((121, 154, 210), (142, 150, 92)), ((127, 219, 167), (121, 154, 210)), ((197, 223, 252), (79, 247, 87)), ((127, 219, 167), (79, 247, 87)), ((127, 219, 167), (142, 150, 92)), ((121, 154, 210), (104, 132, 238)), ((104, 132, 238), (197, 223, 252)), ((127, 219, 167), (197, 223, 252)), ((222, 190, 134), (121, 154, 210)), ((191, 52, 233), (121, 154, 210)), ((222, 190, 134), (191, 52, 233)), ((191, 52, 233), (127, 219, 167)), ((191, 52, 233), (222, 190, 134))]
expect = [(142, 150, 92), (133, 228, 115), (149, 198, 219), (250, 150, 227), (79, 247, 87), (197, 223, 252), (104, 132, 238), (121, 154, 210), (127, 219, 167), (191, 52, 233), (222, 190, 134)]

rules.remove(((191, 52, 233), (222, 190, 134)))

ts = TopologicalSorter()
for color in colors:
    ts.add(color)
for rule in rules:
    ts.add(*rule)
ordered = list(ts.static_order())

print(ordered)
print(ordered == expect)
```

Output:

```
[(142, 150, 92), (133, 228, 115), (149, 198, 219), (250, 150, 227), (79, 247, 87), (197, 223, 252), (104, 132, 238), (121, 154, 210), (127, 219, 167), (191, 52, 233), (222, 190, 134)]
True
```